# how to start separate thread inside of callback method that returns a value?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, return-value

i wanted to put the code inside of this callback method into a separate thread to prevent the slow blocking of the processing time for this code for increase in execution speed, however when it try this it gives me an error from the compiler that there is no return from the method.

it looks like the compiler wants the return to be outside of the new thread that I started.

how can make the code in the return method run as a separate process of execution?

```
 public Mat onCameraFrame(final CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

 new Thread(){
   public void run() {

   mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
   mGray = inputFrame.gray();

   MatOfRect circles = new MatOfRect();

      Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mGray, mGray, new Size(5, 5), 2, 2);  

     Imgproc.HoughCircles( mGray, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,
     1, mGray.rows()/8, 150, 50, 0, 0 );

 if (circles.cols() > 0)
 for (int x = 0; x < circles.cols(); x++) 
 {
 double vCircle[] = circles.get(0,x);

 if (vCircle == null)
 break;

 Point pt = new Point(Math.round(vCircle[0]), Math.round(vCircle[1]));
     int radius = (int)Math.round(vCircle[2]);

 // draw the found circle
 Core.circle(mRgba, pt, radius, new Scalar(0,255,0), 7);
 Core.circle(mRgba, pt, 3, new Scalar(0,0,255), 7);
 }

 return mRgba; // <-- complier wants this to be outside of this thread

 } // end run
 }.start();

 } // oncameraframe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Runnable` `interface` cannot return a value. Use `Callable` `interface`.

Example with executors:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Future<Integer> f = executor.submit(new Callable<Integer>()
{
    public Integer call()
    {
        return 2;
    }
});
```

Object f will hold your result.

In your example `mRgba` is field, so it can be later accessed. You can use synchronize it and you do not have to return result. Result can be kept in this variable.